# Return model class objects Dynamically

Tags: java, spring-mvc

This may be a simple and basic question, but I am struggling here. I want to return model class object based on some action. For example;

```
 Employee emp = Library.getModelObject("employee"); //LibraryManagementController.java

    public static Object getModelObject(String action){   // Library.java

       if(action.equals("employee")){
         Employee emp = new Employee();
         return emp;
       }else if(action.equals("student")){
         Student student = new Student();
         return student;
       }else{
         return null;
       }

    }
```

Comment: Are you using annotations? Also, is this a controllre method?

Comment: Not enough data. Could you please give more details? Is this a code in controller?

Comment: You cannot use Employee emp = getModelObject("employee"), since you cannot be sure what type would getModelObject() returns

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.I have a method in service class and i am invoking it from the Spring Controller.

Comment: Currently i am using RequestParam and ResponseBody annotations

Comment: I tried both in Service class that working fine,but not working with Controller and Service class.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good case for a factory strategy pattern. Define a factory interface and then implementations of it to create the right type. You should also consider using generics to handle the different types.

Comment: Can you give me some example by using generics please.